# Adding time to Raster Mosiac Footprint using ArcPy?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, spatial-analyst, mosaic

I am trying to create a raster mosiac for use in animating data over time.  The current workflow is:

- Create .gdb (`arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management`)
- Create Raster Mosaic (`arcpy.CreateMosaicDataset_management`)
- Add rasters to mosaic (`arcpy.AddRastersToMosaicDataset_management`)

The above are all working well.

Next I created a new "date" field in the Footprint feature class.  What I would like is to do now is for each row in the Footprint table to add a time into the date field.  However I seem to be unable to do this.  I assume it is because the Footprint layer is treated different than a normal feature class.

Do I need to use a footprint specific command (`arcpy.BuildFootprints_management`)?

Comment: It looks like you need a mosaic of mosaics.  Check [this](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009t000000v1000000]) for arc10.1.